# Can't get request.user sub fields

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm quite new to Django/Python and I'm having trouble to retrieve the `user` attributes, such as `first_name`. What am I missing?

```
class principal(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):

template_name = 'appPortal/index.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    usuario = self.request.user
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    print (usuario)  ### OK, returns the logged user
    print (usuario.first_name)  ### Don't work, returns nothing
    print (usuario.get_short_name()) ### Don't work too
### The code continues, but the last two print() don't work
```

Thanks,

Comment: The name fields are allowed to be blank - are you sure the user has a name?

Comment: Yep, that wasn't actually set. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you don't allow the required fields to be blank!